# Relation between positive definiteness and the quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

I am taking a linear algebra course and recently learned about the concept of a positive definite matrix through the framing of the quadratic form.

I understand that every matrix in a quadratic form is positive definite, but am I correct in thinking that all matrices can potentially show positive definite behavior? That is, is the concept of positive definite only applicable to the quadratic form?

Comment: What, to you, is a "quadratic form"?  Is $-x^2$ a quadratic form in the variable $x$?  If so, its matrix is *not* positive definite.

Comment: I am referring to the quadratic form as discussed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form. The matrix $M$ of such a polynomial $q(t)$, are such that $q(t) = x^TMx$

Comment: Where did you get the idea that every matrix of a quadratic form is positive-definite?

Comment: I didn't quite say that. In my original post, I stated that matrices of quadratic form exhibit some sort of behavior relating to the concept of positive definite (positive semidefinite, negative semidefinite....).

Comment: “... every matrix in a quadratic form is positive definite ...” If that’s not what you meant to say, I suggest that you reword it.

Comment: One can define positive-definiteness &c for any square matrix, but those terms are usually applied only to symmetric matrices since only the symmetric part of a matrix contributes to a quadratic form.